# QuickBlox "Unexpected Signature" error while making session with REST Api in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, quickblox, hmacsha1

This might be a repeated question but I can't find anything about what is wrong about it, I have been trying to generate a session via QuickBlox's rest API, it has consumed 5 days but I can't get it through. Please help me out

Setting the body

```
NSString *strNonceValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arc4random() % 1000000];
    NSString *timeStampValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

NSMutableDictionary *dictSessionInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            applicationID, @"application_id",
                                            _pAuthorizationKey, @"auth_key",
                                            timeStampValue, @"timestamp",
                                            strNonceValue, @"nonce", nil];

NSString *signature = [self generateSignatureWithText:dataVal andKey:_pAuthorizationKey];

[dictSessionInfo setObject:signature forKey:@"signature"];

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictSessionInfo options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Getting Signature

```
- (NSString *)generateSignatureWithText:(NSData *)data andKey:(NSString *)secret {

    NSData *secretData = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *clearTextData = data;
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
    CCHmacContext hmacContext;
    CCHmacInit(&hmacContext, kCCHmacAlgSHA1, secretData.bytes, secretData.length);
    CCHmacUpdate(&hmacContext, clearTextData.bytes, clearTextData.length);
    CCHmacFinal(&hmacContext, digest);
    NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSString *hash = [result description];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    return hash;   
}
```

Generating URLRequest

```
requestURL = [requestURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL];
NSString *postLength=@"";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setURL:url];
NSLog(@"HTTP body Fields : %@", combinedDataStr);
if([requestType isEqualToString:@"POST"]) {
    NSData *postData = [combinedDataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                     allowLossyConversion:YES];
    postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
}
else
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"0.1.0"            forHTTPHeaderField:@"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version"];
```

The response I am receiving is :

```
response dict : {
    errors =     {
        base =         (
            "Unexpected signature"
        );
    };
}
```

Please look into this and let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: did you solve your problem? if yes then can you post the solution as i ma having same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue I have faced. I have tried to solve this issue please try below step

1. Uninstall
   pod 'QuickBlox'
2. Reinstall Quickblox pod file it will take Latest framework and Rebuild projects,

You will see the magic of this issue by solved :)
Please let me know above steps are worked for you?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the problem is with this line

```
NSString *signature = [self generateSignatureWithText:dataVal andKey:_pAuthorizationKey];
```

you use auth key to create a signature, but you should pass here secret key

so, try to replace _pAuthorizationKey with secret key

Comment: Thanks @Igor Khomenko, I will test it and will update here soon

Comment: i just found that you are a developer in quickblox.a am trying to implement the video chat in my app. but unable to get valid signature.can you help me how to get the valid signature.in this question i can not unserstand what is `dataval` passed in the method.please help if possible

Comment: @Igor what is dataVal? What needs to go in here?